# Add speed to this toggle

Tags: jquery

I have this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.toggle_expand_button').click(function(){
    $('.toggle_expand').toggleClass("tog_ex_hide tog_ex_show");
});
});
```

I wish to add speed to the toggle ( say 1000 milliseconds )

I thought it would be as simple as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.toggle_expand_button').click(function(){
    $('.toggle_expand').toggleClass('1000','tog_ex_hide tog_ex_show');
});
  });
```

LOL obviously I was wrong :(

Comment: You were wrong, adding a class has no particular speed, but jQuery UI does have similar functionality.

Comment: What are you achieving by adding speed while adding the class? class will be added instantaneously. Did you mean to delay it or animate it?

Comment: i want the toggle to animate so opens / closes slowly, perhaps i should use show hide ?

Comment: Use `fadeToggle` or `slideToggle` for that.

Comment: I tried: $('.toggle_expand').slideToggle("slow", function("tog_ex_hide tog_ex_show")); but it just aint working captain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to show and hide it use `.toggle(1000)`.

you can animate other properties using the `.animate()`
but u'll be loosing the "toggle" function... so you have to devise your own logic of knowing the toggle state...

if you really need to animate a class with a bunch of cool css in it...

You need to use jQuery UI....

http://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/

Comment: cheers, kind of lost because I am using jquery ui, will ditch this code and re do it from scratch. Thanks